# Stopping all sounds at once?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, avaudioplayer

Hello
I have 16 sounds in a view. And they loops etc. I want a rect button where you tap it all the sounds stop.
Here is the code i used for one of the sounds, its the same for the rest.#

```
- (IBAction)twoSound:(id)sender; {
    if (twoAudio && twoAudio.playing) {
        [twoAudio stop];
        [twoAudio release];
        twoAudio = nil;
        return;
    }    
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (twoAudio) [twoAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    twoAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    twoAudio.delegate = self;
    [twoAudio play];    

}
```

I tried

```
-(IBAction)goStop:(id)sender; {

    [oneAudio, twoAudio, threeAudio, fourAudio, fiveAudio, sixAudio, sevenAudio, eightAudio, nineAudio, tenAudio, elevenAudio, twelveAudio, thirteenAudio, fourteenAudio, fifthteenAudio, sixteenAudio stop]; 
}
```

But that didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Makes you wish Objective-C had ActionScript's `stopAllSounds()` or something :)

Comment: Lol yeah i wish! I guess I tried the lazy way .. and steve jobs probably dont like lazy people :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use an NSArray instead of many sound objects. So you can easily fill the array with the 12 sounds and then you can use a "for" cycle to stop them all.

Comment: or an NSMutableArray if you need it

Comment: This is probably the best answer to this. Either use an `NSArray` of pre-defined `AVAudioPlayer` objects, or create an `NSMutableArray` to keep track of those objects as you create them.